# how to insert xmlns and xlink attributes into svg element/tag generated by c3 charts?

Tags: svg, charts, c3.js, css-to-pdf

I am planning to export c3 charts using https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf. But CSS2PDF requires the SVG tags to contain attributes xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" and xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
to be a valid for export.

How to add these two attributes to svg element generated by c3 chart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var svg = $('#chart').find('svg')[0];
    svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
    svg.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

     });
```